# Drupal Delta node/block template suggestions

Tags: drupal-theming

From reading the documentation, you can dynamically theme Drupal blocks and nodes by adding template files: "page-node-1.tpl" or "block-modulename-2.tpl".

1. How do i know the delta value(in this case 1 or 2) to create a template file for node or block?
2. Do these delta values keep changing?
3. What assigns these delta values and when?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to admin/build/block, then move
   cursor over any  'configure' link in
   the block list.You'll see for
   example
   'admin/build/block/configure/views/news-block_2'
   path. It means this block provided
   by 'Views' module and has delta
   'news-block_2'
2. No
3. Modules